# If $(n^2-n) $ is divisible by m and I have given the value of m , how can I find the value of n where n<m?

Tags: number-theory

If $(n^2-n) $ is divisible by m and I have given the value of m , how can I find the value of n ?  Here $ n<m . $
My idea is :

$ n^2-n = mk \\$

$ n^2-n-mk=0 \\$

n can be rational if the determinant of the equation is sqaure . $ D= 1+4mk $ My wish is to find the value of k for which D is a sqaure . Then for this value of k I can find the value of n . But this process is too long . Can you please help me to find this out ?

Comment: please specify the question, there are infinitely many such $n$'s, take for example $n = km$ for natural $k$.

Comment: I have to find all possible values of n .

Comment: observe that $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$ and those two numbers are relatively prime.

Comment: What observation should I take from this ?

Comment: @Lucian - not really, noone said $m$ was prime. you have to decompose $m$ into prime factors and work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $m | n(n-1)$
The greatest common divisor of $n,m$ divides $n$
The rest must divide $n-1$, since $n$ and $n-1$ are coprime.
For arbitrary $n$ this greatest common divisor can be really any factor of $m$.
So you can break your $m|n(n-1)$ into $k|n$ and $m/k | n-1$ for any $k|m$

Of course, for this to make sense you would need $k$ and $m/k$ to be coprime.
Then just use solve each ($k|n$ and $m/k | n-1$) individually.